# Modifying JSON key values in Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to load a JSON file and change specific key values then save the updated entries to a new file. This JSON file has many entries with the same format.  This is my furthest attempt before coming here, however it does not save the new values.

What am I missing?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import simplejson as json
import names

in_file = open('Names.json', 'r')
out_file = open('Names_new.json','w')

data_file = in_file.read()
data = json.loads(data_file)

for x in data:
    nickname = x['nickname']
    newname = names.get_first_name()    
    nickname = newname

out_file.write(json.dumps(data))
out_file.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't change x['nickname'] when you wanted to assign `newname` to it. Instead, you only modified the variable `nickname`.

Try assigning the `x['nickname']` directly:

```
for x in data:
    x['nickname'] = names.get_first_name()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are just dumping old JSON data again into a new file without modifying its contents.

Instead, you should change the contents of the file with `newname`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import simplejson as json
import names

in_file = open('Names.json', 'r')
out_file = open('Names_new.json','w')

data_file = in_file.read()
data = json.loads(data_file)

for x in data:
    newname = names.get_first_name()    
    x['nickname'] = newname

out_file.write(json.dumps(data))
out_file.close()
```