# Changing json values and making new ones

Tags: python, json

I am trying to write new data to existing json with no luck. Heres my current json file dat.dat:

```
{"users": {"tryhard_cupcake": {"Points": 0, "Time Joined": 9938}}}
```

and how I'm parsing it:

```
def updateUsers(chan):
    j = urllib2.urlopen('http://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/' + chan + '/chatters')
    j_obj = json.load(j)
    with open('dat.dat', 'r+w') as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)
        for dat in data['users']:
            if dat in j_obj['chatters']['moderators']:
                points=data['users'][dat]['Points']
                json.dump(points + 50, data_file)

updateUsers('tryhard_cupcake')
```

which I was expecting to add 50 points to the user but rather it just appended a 50 to the end of the file. The output was this:

```
{"users": {"tryhard_cupcake": {"Points": 0, "Time Joined": 9938}}}
50
```

How do I go about appending new data to users and modifying it? I was expecting this result:

```
{"users": {"tryhard_cupcake": {"Points": 50, "Time Joined": 9938}}}
```

Comment: all that `json.dump` does is write whatever your parameter is to your `data_file`. what you want is to replace your actual data with `data['users'][dat']['Points']+=50` then overwrite your whole json file with your new dict

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying JSON key values in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591231/modifying-json-key-values-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Load json data of file in variable.
2. Change variable.
3. Write json variable in file again.

Change your `updateUsers` like this:

```
def updateUsers(chan):
    j = urllib2.urlopen('http://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/' + chan + '/chatters')
    j_obj = json.load(j)
    with open('dat.dat') as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)
        for dat in data['users']:
            if dat in j_obj['chatters']['moderators']:
                data['users'][dat]['Points'] += 50
    # write to file
    with open('dat.dat', 'w') as out_file:
        json.dump(data, out_file)
```

Comment: Gives a ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Answer (score 0):

You can find similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591231/modifying-json-key-values-in-python/33591278#33591278) .
Use

```
            data['users'][dat]['Points']=50
```

to change value of points. You are making a new variable `points=data['users'][dat]['Points']` and changing value o that variable, not the value of 'points' in data